# How can I overwrite a pyspark DataFrame with a different schema

Tags: pyspark

I changed the data type on a column of my DataFrame and I'd like to store it in the same location as the old version. Even though I specify "overwrite" and delete the dir, this minimal example gives an error message "pyspark.errors.exceptions.AnalysisException: Failed to merge fields 'label' and 'label'. Failed to merge incompatible data types StringType and DoubleType":

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, "foo"),
        (2, "bar"),
    ],
    ["id", "label"]
)

path = Path("/dbfs/mnt/location")

shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=True)
path.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
df.write.mode("overwrite").save(str(path))

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 1.5),
        (2, 2.5),
    ],
    ["id", "label"]
)
shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=True)
path.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
df.write.mode("overwrite").save(str(path))
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your error with pyspark 3.4.0. Which version are you using?

Comment: Spark has a lazy execution it means that it reads the input bit by bit, so the input dir has to be different from the output dir, you need to save in some other location and then remove the old dir and move the new one the old location

Comment: @AlexandreJuma 3.3.2.dev0 on Azure Databricks